# how to use datestr2num instead of strpdate2num

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The strpdate2num class was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use time.strptime or dateutil.parser.parse or datestr2num instead. However i tried different method and just keep getting error, the most common error message is ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '%Y-%m-%d')

i have tried time.strptime, dateutil.parser.parse and datestr2num, but none of those are correct, i have no idea what i get wrong

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.datestr2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter


def graph_data(stock):
    # Unfortunately, Yahoo's API is no longer available
    # feel free to adapt the code to another source, or use this drop-in replacement.
    stock_price_url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
    stock_data = []
    split_source = source_code.split('\n')
    for line in split_source[1:]:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        if len(split_line) == 7:
            if 'values' not in line and 'labels' not in line:
                stock_data.append(line)

    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, adj_closep, volume = np.loadtxt(  stock_data,
                                                                        delimiter=',',
                                                                        unpack=True,
                                                                        # %Y = full year. 2015
                                                                        # %y = partial year 15
                                                                        # %m = number month
                                                                        # %d = number day
                                                                        # %H = hours
                                                                        # %M = minutes
                                                                        # %S = seconds
                                                                        # 12-06-2014
                                                                        # %m-%d-%Y
                                                                        converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

    plt.plot_date(date, closep,'-', label='Price')

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


graph_data('TSLA')
```

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: You should check the formatting of your data then which is probably not in the format of a date like `2018-03-21`. Provide some sample data or the dates you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dateformat seems quite common, so `strconverter = mdates.datestr2num` should work (no fmt argument). Of course in that case the complete converter can be simplified to

```
def bytespdate2num(b):
    return mdates.datestr2num(b.decode('utf-8'))
```

and use it like

```
converters={0: bytespdate2num}
```

Comment: This helps resolving following error: `numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toordinal'`

Answer (score 1):

i have stuck on this and now finally got the solution and here an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib.request as urq
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import requests


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return (mdates.datestr2num(s))
    return bytesconverter

def graph_data():

    stock_price_url='https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'
    source_code = urq.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

    stock_data = []
    split_source = source_code.split('\n')

    for line in split_source:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        if len(split_line) is 7:
            if 'Volume' not in line:
                stock_data.append(line)

    datep, openp, highp, lowp, closep, ad_closep, vol = np.loadtxt(stock_data,
                                                                  delimiter=',',
                                                                  unpack=True,
                                                                  converters={0:bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')}
                                                                  )

    plt.plot_date(datep, closep, '-', label='Price')

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

graph_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

def bytespdate2num (fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s= b.decode(encoding)
        return (mdates.datestr2num(s))
    return bytesconverter

def graph_data(stock):
    stock_price_url = urllib.request.Request('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/'+stock+'?period1=1633102184&period2=1664638184&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true')
    status_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).getcode()
    with urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url) as sc:
        source_code = sc.read().decode()
    print(status_code)
         
        

    stock_data =[]
    split_source = source_code.split('\n')
    for line in split_source[1:]:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        if len(split_line) == 7:
            if 'values' not in line and 'labels' not in line:
                stock_data.append(line)

    date, openp, highp, lowp, closep, adjclose, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_data, 
    delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters= {0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})

    plt.plot_date(date,  closep, '-', label='PRICE')
    plt.xlabel('DATE')
    plt.ylabel('PRICE')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
graph_data(stock='TSLA')
```

Comment: Using the help from 'Ayeman Hossain Ashik' above I was able to generate the solution from a MacOS

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!